# System.Data.OracleClient for Oracle 11 Client .NET component

Tags: c#, .net, oracle11g

My App is written for Oracle 10. It uses `System.Data.OracleClient`
Is there the same component for Oracle 11 under x64 System?

Comment: Microsoft announced the end of that namespace in favor of Oracle's own ADO.NET provider a long time ago, so make sure you know the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, since 11 x64 it's called Oracle.DataAccess.. 
you should recompile everything under x64 to be able to exchange data to Ora.

It you deal with Ora11 x32, then System.Data.OracleClient will work fine.

Comment: Is it part of Oracle DB or Ora Client package?

Comment: if you write an App for client connection, I suggest you use Client pack, though it's in Ora DB as well.